# PHP class property initiated as stdClass

Tags: php

Basically what I want to do is this

```
class A {

    public $prop = new stdClass;

}
```

And PHP is telling me I can't do this:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in - on line ##

What's up with that? I know that you basically can't assign a function's return value to a property in initialization, but can someone explain why is that, like the technical stuff. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use class constructor:

```
class A {

    public $prop;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->prop = new stdClass;

    }

}
```

[PHP manual says:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

> Declaration of properties may include an initialization, but this
> initialization must be a constant value - that is, it must be able to
> be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
> information in order to be evaluated.

Comment: But how is an empty stdClass not a constant?

Comment: PHP doesn't check what you're trying to instantiate. in this case, it's just parsing the code and sees you're trying to use a dynamic available-at-execution-time-only code structure and bails out. Doesn't matter if stdclass is "empty" right now anyways. In the future it may not be.

Answer (score 1):

class variables must be initialized with static values, e.g.

```
public $prop = 7; // ok
public $prop = 7+7; // ok - can be evaluated at compile time
public $prop = new stdClass; // bad, dynamic result.
public $prop = get_some_value(); //also bad, dynamic result not available at compile time
```

Comment: Well yeah, I came to that conclusion. I'm actually asking what's causing that.

Comment: It's a PHP restriction. The only way to get around it is to define the class variables with null/default fixed values, and then assign the dynamic stuff in the constructor.